# Facebook SDK for Android - set Application ID programmatically

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have a native Android app that needs to connect to a different Facebook app (different Application ID) based on an app setting that can be changed at runtime.

Imagine the app can be set to point to DEV, TEST, or PROD. When pointed to DEV the FB Application ID should be "1". When pointed to TEST the FB Application ID should be "2". etc.

The problem is the UiLifecycleHelper from the Facebook SDK automatically reads the "com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" from the AndroidManifest.xml during the onCreate phase. There doesn't appear to be a way to set this programmatically.

Is it possible to use UiLifecycleHelper and point to a different application ID at runtime or do I have to fall back to manually managing the Session?

Comment: You can follow the idea of Ravi Kumar. But it will not work for any FacebookDialogs. For dialogs, you can write your own constructor for the DialogBuilders in the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to fork the facebook-android-sdk project on GitHub and make the necessary changes. I have submitted a pull request with my changes if anyone is interested, https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/294.

Answer (score 26):

Hello all i know above answer is right for `older sdk version`, but in `facebook sdk 4` there is no `Session` class

You can simply do it by using this single line code:

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(APP_ID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we do it anytime or it has to be before FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() ?

Answer (score 13):

Here what i used to set the application id programatcally

```
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String s=""+R.string.app_id;

    Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(s).build();

    Session.setActiveSession(session);

    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(session.isOpened()){
            //Do your task
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant get this to work. the if session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED) is being skipped over

Comment: How is this used in conjunction with UIHelper?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set it programmatically. Use the Sessions$Builder class which allows you to build a session without needing to use one of the private constructors.

```
Session session = new Session.Builder(context).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
```

Comment: How do you use this in conjunction with UIHelper?

Comment: I check to see if I have a valid session before invoking the UiLifecycleHelper via callback. I imagine it's not as elegant as a custom forked version but it keeps our maintenance down.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler way to do this, just call the static method setApplicationId `com.facebook.Settings.setApplicationId(facebookID);`

And you're good to go. No need to create a session manually with the Builder and set it as the active session!

**Details of the Flaw:**

The facebookID you set in the settings class will be used by `getMetadataApplicationId` method of `com.facebook.internal.Utility`

```
public static String getMetadataApplicationId(Context context) {
        Validate.notNull(context, "context");

        Settings.loadDefaultsFromMetadata(context);

        return Settings.getApplicationId();
    }
```

Which in turn will be used by all the calls to create a Session:

```
Session(Context context, String applicationId, TokenCachingStrategy tokenCachingStrategy,
            boolean loadTokenFromCache) {
        // if the application ID passed in is null, try to get it from the
        // meta-data in the manifest.
        if ((context != null) && (applicationId == null)) {
            applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(context);
        }

        Validate.notNull(applicationId, "applicationId");
.
.
.
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Good find but `getMetadataApplicationId` is called only if app id = null that means you cannot update you app id if you already have one.