# How to add metadata dynamically (Not in manifest but inside code)?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to set app meta data using code. Is it possible in Android ?
Trying to set Facebook app id into code not inside manifest.

```
meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"android:value="@string/applicationId"
```

Please help me.

Comment: This link shows how to add app Id for facebook: [ADD DYNAMICALLY Facebook APP ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072937/facebook-sdk-for-android-set-application-id-programmatically/17016077#17016077)

Comment: its working nicely... Just add metadata into the manifest file as a place holder

Answer (score 8):

> I want to set app meta data using code.Is it possible in android ?

No, it's not possible. The manifest get's parsed at compile time -> you can't add meta-data at runtime.

Comment: is it possible to add value of appid at run time ?

Comment: No I'm afraid this is not possible either.

Comment: Is it possible to either add/remove or enable/disable a `meta-data` tag in the Manifest? For instance, a web browser app implementing `WebView` that offers users the ability to [opt-in/out of Google metrics collection](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview#metrics).

Answer (score 2):

for add any metadata dynamically you can use this code:

```
try {
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            applicationInfo.metaData.putString("Your Key", "Your Value");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, despite being semantically correct

Answer (score 0):

Hello all i know above answer is right for older sdk version, but in

```
facebook sdk 4+
```

there is no **Session class**

You can simply do it by using this single line code:

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(APP_ID);
```

Thanks!