# Programatically set meta-data content in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

Can we set the content of meta-data tag programmatically i.e without using manifest.Here is a code snippet from manifest

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.vr.application.mode"
            android:value="vr_only"/>
```

.......

Comment: No you cannot change the **meta-data** element at runtime.

Comment: for add any metadata dynamically you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732632/3999469): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732632/3999469

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. `<meta-data>` elements are only set at compile time.

The particular library that you are using that requires the `<meta-data>` element might offer some way to configure it via Java code, instead of the `<meta-data>` element. The details of this would vary by library.