# Set Facebook Application Id programmatically in 4.x

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Back in SDK 3.x, I used as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072937/facebook-sdk-for-android-set-application-id-programmatically):

```
session = newSession.Builder(Activity).setApplicationId(String).build();
```

But since there is no Session class in 4.x, how can I set the application Id programmatically? I know it should be in the resources, but I am actually building a library and expecting to receive it from a client application so setting it in JAVA is my only option.

Comment: yes absolutely right and in your prevous question i have already answered for newer sdk so you can check your answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(yourId)`

More detail here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/